# Mysql type limit function on redis

Tags: redis

I am using python to access the data in redis. I want to access keys depending on a pattern, but I don't want all the keys, I just want to put a limit on the output, just like the mysql limit function. Obviously, I can get all the keys depending on the pattern and then just slice my list, but the the problem is I don't want to fetch that much of data, I just want to fetch a sample, because there are millions of keys, for that pattern. Is there a way to do this? I am sure people would be facing this problem. How do they go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `SCAN` command together with `MATCH` and `COUNT` option. But please note that `COUNT` is just a hint for the implementation, there is no guarantee.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match key-* count 5
1) "49152"
2) 1) "key-30266"
   2) "key-45938"
   3) "key-59166"
   4) "key-46033"
   5) "key-24326"
```

Choose `SCAN` `SSCAN` `ZSCAN` `HSCAN` denpending on you key type.

Please read the [SCAN Reference](http://redis.io/commands/scan) carefully. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command, optionally with the `LIMIT` option.